# v-for with filter gives error of property or method not defined

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm using Vue2 with Vuex.
I have a list of posts from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts
I want to show it in descending order.
for that, I created a filter named "desc" in main.js and applied to my component posts.vue like this.

```
<li v-for="post in posts | desc" :key="post.id">
```

this is my main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import { store } from './store/store'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.filter('desc', function(arr){
  if(arr) return arr.reverse();
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  store,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

it gives me the following error:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "desc" is not defined on the instance
> but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is
> reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by
> initializing the property. See:
> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

I thought it may cause this error until http get request comes with the response. To troubleshoot this I also tried with static json data but still shows this error.

can any one help me out solving this?

Comment: From documentation `Vue.js allows you to define filters that can be used to apply common text formatting.`. Use computed or method to get reversed array

Answer (score 3):

Try using slice().reverse() in v-for.

```
<li v-for="post in posts.slice().reverse()">
    //do something here
</li>
```